# If question fails to be updated, can I post a new question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've been looking for TF2 hats that have been free to get (via free games, etc.)

I posted a new post, but was told to simply award a bounty on a pre-existing post.

What I'm concerned with is that the post won't get answered.  It won't be updated, etc.  And more than that, I'll never get an answer (well I will, eventually).

If I've been waiting long enough for an answer to come around, can I simply bring up a new post to refresh everything?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29035/what-hats-in-tf2-are-or-were-available-for-free Here's the link.  I've been waiting for a couple of days, no response.  I feel like it might not get updated, which is why I would like to post a new post.  However, that's apparently against the rules of the site, so....

Comment: If updating the old question with an edit asking for the details it is missing or placing a bounty isn't going to attract an answer, I don't think a new question would either.

Comment: I think one of the problems with the existing question is the best answer is a community wiki, so updating it would be the best solution, but wouldn't necessarily yield the rep...

Comment: Right now there are so many bounty questions (diablo 3) that you'd actually have to look for the question in order to actually see it. If it was a new question, it might attract new questions, and as always, new edits or answers "bump" the topic back to the top.

Comment: @Retrosaur It's unclear to me why you think a brand new question would be more likely to be answered.

Comment: I'm probably sure this is just me, but I think more people peruse the "newest" or "unanswered" questions than people who peruse "featured" questions.

Comment: @Retrosaur when people suggested that you place a bounty on the old question, I was not sure it would lead to anyone updating that question, which led me to post this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134003/bounties-on-question-with-cw-answer-do-not-reward-people-for-improving-existing. Not that it's accomplished anything, but you might want to look at it.

Comment: Many thanks. I really appreciate it @murgatroid99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't post a new question, and—as [you experienced](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/71210/3389)—doing so will result in the question being quickly closed.

Stack Exchange is meant to create lasting bits of information: canonical pairs of questions and answers. Recreating the same question over and over actively harms this project.

If a question hasn't received an appropriate answer yet, there are several things you can do:

- Update the question to clarify the problem or update with what you've found so far, making it easier for others to contribute
- If there are answers already, revise the question to explain why the problem isn't solved by the existing answers
- Offer a bounty

All of these things will bump the question to the top of the active questions list, just as creating a new question would.

And just to clarify how bounties function; [you mentioned in the comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4787/if-question-fails-to-be-updated-can-i-post-a-new-question#comment13670_4787) that you haven't offered (or won't offer) a bounty because:

> Right now there are so many bounty questions (diablo 3) that you'd actually have to look for the question in order to actually see it. If it was a new question, it might attract new questions, and as always, new edits or answers "bump" the topic back to the top.

Firstly, as mentioned above, offering a bounty bumps a question just as an edit or new answer would.

Secondly, the featured tab is ordered by how long the bounty has before it expires: your bounty will eventually appear at the top of that list.

Finally, [this isn't 'nam](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUfec8S10MI): there are rules. Your question isn't more or less special than the other questions that haven't received much love. The bounty system is intended to be a fair way for people to "bump" their questions in an orderly fashion by paying reputation to entice people to answer. Trying to jump to the head of the pack, so to speak, by re-asking your question and without backing the bump with reputation is kind of a cheese move. Imagine if everyone did that!

Comment: In my experience, the bounty also increases your question's SEO dramatically.  So not only do you get the attention of more users of the site, you get the attention of more new users. In my experience - thousands more views. A new question on an old game may stay under a hundred views indefinitely.

Comment: I actually posted a bounty on the original question as suggested to me by other SE users.